# How to call a js method in my template with RequireJS in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, custom-options, jquery, requirejs

In `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/web/js/price-options.js` there is a method `_onOptionChanged: function onOptionChanged(event)`.

I would like to call this method in my template when page load.

```
app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/options/wrapper.phtml
```

How can i achieve this? is it possible to call this method in my template file ? if possible please help me and suggest me how can do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it in template, and you can't access directly to a private method. You can do it in a requireJS module through the **mixins** configuration.

See the [docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_mixins.html).

In your case you could do something like his:

```
var config = {
    'config':{
        'mixins': {
            'priceOptions': {
                'Vendor_Module/script' : true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

And in your script.js

```
define(['jquery'], function ($) {

    return function (widget) {

       $.widget('mage.priceOptions', widget, {

           yourMethod: function () {
                 this._onOptionChanged
           }

       });
       return $.mage.priceOptions;
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply @nuovecode I will check and update you.

Comment: Hi @nuovedcode could you please help me on this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/319106/magento2-restrict-cc-number-in-the-form-fields