# Magento2 restrict cc number in the form fields

Tags: magento2, customer-account, form-validation, restriction

I would like to restrict CC number (Ex: 4111111111111111) in the customer form fields in the magento2 frontend.
Could you please advise me on how to do the step by step in Magento2.

**Expected Results:**

[image: Expected Results For All Form input fields]

**The approach I have followed:**

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Ui/js/lib/validation/validator': {
                'Vendor_Module/js/validator-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/validator-mixin.js

```
define([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    "use strict";

    return function () {
        $.validator.addMethod(
            'validation16digit',
            function (v) {
            console.log("validation16digit has been calling");
                 v = v.replace(/-/g,""); v = v.replace(/ /g,"");  return !((/^\d+$/.test(v)) && ( (/([0-9]\d{12}(?:\d{3})?)/.test(v)) || (/(3[47]\d{13})/.test(v)) || (/(^(?:2131|1800|35\d{3})\d{11}$)/.test(v)) || (/((?:5020|5038|6304|6579|6761)\d{12}(?:\d\d)?)/.test(v)) || (/((?:6334|6767)\d{12}(?:\d\d)?\d?)/.test(v)) || (/(5[1-5]\d{14})/.test(v)) || (/(?:(?:(?:4903|4905|4911|4936|6333|6759)\d{12})|(?:(?:564182|633110)\d{10})(\d\d)?\d?)/.test(v))));

                return v;
            },
            $.mage.__('Please Enter Valid Input')
        );
    }
});
```

app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frotend/layout/default_head_blocks.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <script src="Vendor_Module::js/ccnumber1.js"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frotend/web/js/ccnumber1.js

```
require(['jquery'],
function($) {
    "use strict";

    $(document).ready(function() {
    customValidations();
        function customValidations() {
            console.log("cc validatiaon calling");
            $('.input-text').each(function() {

                $(this).addClass("validation16digit");
            });
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new validation rule with:

`Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/model/validation16digit.js`

```
define(
    ['mage/translate', 'Magento_Ui/js/model/messageList'],
    function ($t, messageList) {
        'use strict';
        return {
            validate: function () {
                const isValid = false; //Put your validation logic here

                if (!isValid) {
                    messageList.addErrorMessage({ message: $t('a possible failure message ...  ') });
                }

                return isValid;
            }
        }
    }
);
```

`Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/view/validation16digit.js`

```
define(
    [
        'uiComponent',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/additional-validators',
        '/js/model/your-validator'
    ],
    function (Component, additionalValidators, yourValidator) {
        'use strict';
        additionalValidators.registerValidator(yourValidator);
        return Component.extend({});
    }
);
```

`Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="additional-payment-validators" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="validation16digit" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/js/view/validation16digit</item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

Source: [link](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/howdoi/checkout/checkout_order.html)